# Why does recvfrom() returns wrong address of sender?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recvfrom

This simple UDP client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PORT 9877
#define BSIZE 256
#define ADDRSTRLEN 19

static char presentation[ADDRSTRLEN];
char *Inet_ntop(const void *src)
{
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, src, presentation, ADDRSTRLEN) == NULL)
    {
        perror("inet_ntop");
    }
    return presentation;
}

int main()
{
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    char recvline[BSIZE], sendline[BSIZE];

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    //localhost
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &servaddr.sin_addr);

    socklen_t servlen = sizeof(servaddr);
    struct sockaddr *replyaddr = malloc(servlen);
    socklen_t replylen;

    while (fgets(sendline, BSIZE, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        sendto(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, servlen);
        printf("serv addr: %s\n", Inet_ntop(&servaddr));

        //recvfrom() should return address of the host this UDP received datagram from (localhost)
        replylen = servlen;
        ssize_t bytesRead = recvfrom(sockfd, recvline, BSIZE, 0, replyaddr, &replylen);
        printf("reply addr: %s\n", Inet_ntop(replyaddr));

        recvline[bytesRead] = '\0';
        puts(recvline);
    }
}
```

will send datagram to server (echo server) on 127.0.0.1:9877. The output is

```
a
serv addr: 2.0.38.149
reply addr: 2.0.38.149
a

b
serv addr: 2.0.38.149
reply addr: 2.0.38.149
b

c
serv addr: 2.0.38.149
reply addr: 2.0.38.149
c

^C
```

you can see neither the server address passed `sendto()` (`servaddr`) nor the address from `recvfrom()` (`replyaddr`) is not localhost or `127.0.0.1`. what is `2.0.38.149` ??

tcpdump:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
IP 127.0.0.1.40270 > 127.0.0.1.9877: UDP, length 2
IP 127.0.0.1.9877 > 127.0.0.1.40270: UDP, length 2
IP 127.0.0.1.40270 > 127.0.0.1.9877: UDP, length 2
IP 127.0.0.1.9877 > 127.0.0.1.40270: UDP, length 2
IP 127.0.0.1.40270 > 127.0.0.1.9877: UDP, length 2
IP 127.0.0.1.9877 > 127.0.0.1.40270: UDP, length 2
^C
6 packets captured
12 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

this is correct, and you can see localhost. So what is `2.0.38.149`?

The address 2.0.38.149 is *not* random. I can compile it and run it multiple time and always get the same address, 2.0.38.149. What is that address?

EDIT, server part:

```
void dg_echo(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *cliaddr, socklen_t clilen)
{
    ssize_t bytesRead;
    socklen_t len;
    char buf[BSIZE];

    while (1)
    {
        len = clilen;
        bytesRead = Recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BSIZE, 0, cliaddr, &len);

        Sendto(sockfd, buf, bytesRead, 0, cliaddr, len);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    sockfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    Bind(sockfd, (SA *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    dg_echo(sockfd, (SA *)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the server that echos the packets?  I suspect that your server socket is binding to `INADDR_ANY` instead of `127.0.0.1` explicitly.  If that's the case, these sorts of issues are normal.  Behavior might defer between operating systems.

Comment: yes the server user INADDR_ANY. so what is `2.0.38.149` then? See edits. I added the server part

Comment: Type `ifconfig -a` at the command prompt. I'm guessing you have an adapter with that IP address.

Comment: That's the only interface I have (except of loopback): `wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255`. Do not understand what you meant by 2.0.38.149 address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the wrong thing to `inet_ntop`.

When the first parameter to `inet_ntop` is `AF_INET`, the second parameter should be a pointer to a `struct in_addr`.  What you're passing in is a pointer to a `struct sockaddr_in`.  So the values you're seeing are from the first 4 bytes of the `struct sockaddr_in`.

You need to call your wrapper function like this:

```
Inet_ntop(&servaddr.sin_addr)
```